# Replacement for Google's GeoMap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, geomap

Is there a decent **non-flash** replacement for Google's [GeoMap](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html)? I'm trying to "push" redraws, but because it's flash it has to run back to Google, render a flash object, and then replace it.

Answer (score 9):

Google now has the GeoChart which is the replacement to GeoMap. It creates an SVG and has more flexibility in terms of customization such as changing the background color of the map, etc, etc.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there isn't a free map API as good as this and easy to use.

I've also scoured the web for something I could use that isn't flash but I suppose we have to wait a little while until html 5 gets going something will jump out of the dev bushes with a canvas tag hopefully.

I hope this answers your question. I'll keep looking though. I've been at it for 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

A Google employee [just told me](http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/2112cc36e7959776) they're working on an HTML5 version of the GeoMap API, but it won't be available for a few months.

As for a replacement, this is the  closest I could find, but doesn't offer interactivity, rollovers, or subregions: http://joncom.be/code/excanvas-world-map/

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/ 
It is svg, fully compatible across browsers and has almost everything that google geomaps offers.mit is very easy to implement, more like a jquery plugin amd feeds from json as well.